# Why two python process write the same content to different files

Tags: python

I have 2 shell scripts running at the same time. And there is a python script in each shell script. These python scripts write different contents to different result files. But finally,  the result files are the same with exactly the same create time.

I cannot figure out why this happens.

For example:

```
[hadoop@XXXXX macd]$ ls -l ./data/*.p | tail
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 14 Apr 10 12:37 ./data/603987.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 15 Apr 10 13:48 ./data/603988.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 16 Apr 10 13:48 ./data/603989.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 16 Apr 10 14:00 ./data/603990.p
...
```

```
[hadoop@XXXXX macd]$ ls -l ../kdj/data/*.p | tail
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 14 Apr 10 12:37 ../kdj/data/603987.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 15 Apr 10 13:48 ../kdj/data/603988.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 16 Apr 10 13:48 ../kdj/data/603989.p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 16 Apr 10 14:00 ../kdj/data/603990.p
...
```

Comment: More information: I run these two scripts in the same java process, and the python scripts open the files with the same relative path (But in the shell script, I have set different current work directories).

Comment: We will have a hard time to find that out as well, without any code.

Comment: You have a single java process that is running two shell scripts?

Comment: Yes, a single java process with different threads. And the code is very simple.

Comment: The code is very simple. The shell script, just switchs cwd and runs python script. And python script computes numeric result, opens file with "w" option, then writes content to the file and closes the file. @klaus-d

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find that there is a soft link of the directory. It is not about script and system.